# Is it possible to deploy WSO2 ESB onto a Glassfish Application server

Tags: glassfish, wso2, wso2-esb

Is it possible to deploy the WSO2 ESB onto a Glassfish Application server?  On the WSO2 site (http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB403/ESB+Administration), it list JBoss, Websphere etc, ut no mention of glassfish.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 products use embedded Tomcat as its primary runtime for standalone execution but can also run within other application servers like jboss, glassfish, Websphere, etc.

Comment: Could you point me in the direction of some instructions to install the ESB onto Glassfish (version 2.11)?